# custom sql functions with fluent nhibernate

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate, fluent

How can I use some my SQL function with Fluent NHibernate?

I have some SQL function, for example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[TestFunction] 
(
    @value1 int,
    @vlaue2 int 
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN @value1 + @value2
END
```

And I whant use this function in some of my criteria queries. Can I do this and how?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do this the easiest that I found  was to provide a custom SQL Dialect that registered my function and then used `Session.CreateSQLQuery`to execute it.

Here is a sample custom Dialect:

```
public class CustomMsSql2012Dialect : MsSql2012Dialect
{
    public CustomMsSql2012Dialect ()
    {          
        RegisterFunction("dbo.testfunction", new SQLFunctionTemplate(NHibernateUtil.Int32, "dbo.TestFunction(?1, ?2)"));
    }
}
```

Note that the function name in the first string passed to `RegisterFunction` is all lowercase, in my research I came across someone that said this was required but I can't find that article to cite now unfortunately.

How to use the dialect:

```
MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2012.ConnectionString("connectionStringHere")
    .Dialect<EkaMsSql2012Dialect>();
```

How to call the function:

```
Session.CreateSQLQuery("SELECT dbo.TestFunction( :value1, :value2 )")
     .SetString("value1", 5)
     .SetString("value2", 6)
     .UniqueResult<int>();
```